# How to decrease the space between these tables?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Solution to $\delta$ Orionis from \texttt{PHOEBE 1}.}
\small
\label{result}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,table-column-width=9em}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.57\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format = 3.2(3)]
                }
    \hline\hline
{Parameters}   &{Values}  \\
\hline
$a$ [\Rnom]                   &     41.91(18)        \\
$\omega$ [$^\circ$]                &    148.73(149)      \\
$\gamma$ [ km/s)                &   21.96(33)        \\
$i$ [$^\circ$]                        & 78.1(3)         \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = 2.3,table-space-text-pre=\hspace{0.5em}]
                S[table-format = 2.3,table-space-text-post=\hspace{0.7em}]@{\hskip -0.66em}}
$M_1$  [\Mnom]                          &   21.1        \\
$M_2$ [\Mnom]                           &   8.8         \\
$R_1$ [\Rnom]                           &   13.6        \\
$R_2$ [\Rnom]                           &   3.7         \\
$M_{\mathrm{bol}_1}$ [mag]              &   -8.28           \\
$M_{\mathrm{bol}_2}$ [mag]              &   -4.55        \\
$L_{\mathrm{R}_1}$                      &   0.690           \\
$L_{\mathrm{R}_2}$                      &   0.037           \\
$\log g_1$  [cgs]                           &   3.50            \\
$\log g_2$ [cgs]                        &   4.24            \\
$ \chi^2_\mathrm{N}$                    &  11.389           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\hline\hline
{Fixed param.}              &   {Values}    \\
\hline
$P$ [d]                     &   5.732436$^*$    \\
$\dot{\omega } $ [$^\circ$/d]   &   0.004220$^*$    \\
$q = M_2/M_1$               &   0.41549$^{**}$      \\
$e$                         &   0.07583$^{**}$      \\
$T_{\mathrm{eff}_1}$ [K]    &   31401$^{***}$       \\
$T_{\mathrm{eff}_2}$ [K]    &   25442$^{***}$       \\
$L_{\mathrm{R}_3}$          &   0.273$^{***}$       \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
$^*$ \citet{Mayer2010}

$^{**}$ from \texttt{KOREL}

$^{***}$ from \texttt{Pyterpol}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-20pt}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Why you transform your MWE to code fragment only? Please, extend this fragment (back) to MWE (a complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two different suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[detect-none]{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase = \text{--}} % dashes for range of numbers

\newcommand{\Rnom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{R}_{\odot}$}}
\newcommand{\Mnom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{M}_{\odot}$}}

\usepackage{booktabs} % only used for second example
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table}
  \small
  \label{result}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \centering
  \sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format = 2.2(1.2)]}
    \hline\hline
    {Parameters}     & {Values}  \\
    \hline
    $a$ [\Rnom]      & 41.91(18) \\
    \hline
    $M_1$  [\Mnom]   & 21.1      \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format=1.6, table-space-text-post={$^*$}]}
    \hline\hline
    {Fixed param.}   & {Values}    \\
    \hline
    $P$ [d]          & 5.732436$^*$    \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{***}$ from \texttt{Pyterpol}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \caption{Table}
  \label{result}
  \centering
  \sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format = 2.2(2)]}
    \toprule
    {Parameters}     & {Values}  \\
    \midrule
    $a$ [\Rnom]      & 41.91(18) \\\addlinespace
    $M_1$  [\Mnom]   & 21.1      \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format=1.6, table-space-text-post={$^*$}]}
    \toprule
    {Fixed param.}   & {Values}    \\
    \midrule
    $P$ [d]          & 5.732436$^*$    \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{***}$ from \texttt{Pyterpol}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[detect-none]{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase = \text{--}} % dashes for range of numbers

\newcommand{\Rnom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{R}_{\odot}$}}
\newcommand{\Mnom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{M}_{\odot}$}}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs} % only used for second example
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Solution to $\delta$ Orionis from \texttt{PHOEBE 1}.}
  \small
  \label{result}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format = 3.2(3)]}
      \hline\hline
      {Parameters}   &{Values}  \\
      \hline
      $a$ [\Rnom]                   & 41.91(18)     \\
      $\omega$ [$^\circ$]           & 148.73(149)   \\
      $\gamma$ [ km/s)              & 21.96(33)     \\
      $i$ [$^\circ$]                & 78.1(3)       \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \\
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = -2.3]}
      $M_1$ [\Mnom]                 &   21.1        \\
      $M_2$ [\Mnom]                 &   8.8         \\
      $R_1$ [\Rnom]                 &   13.6        \\
      $R_2$ [\Rnom]                 &   3.7         \\
      $M_{\mathrm{bol}_1}$ [mag]    &   -8.28       \\
      $M_{\mathrm{bol}_2}$ [mag]    &   -4.55       \\
      $L_{\mathrm{R}_1}$            &   0.690       \\
      $L_{\mathrm{R}_2}$            &   0.037       \\
      $\log g_1$  [cgs]             &   3.50        \\
      $\log g_2$ [cgs]              &   4.24        \\
      $ \chi^2_\mathrm{N}$          &  11.389       \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format=1.6, table-space-text-post={$^{***}$}, table-align-text-post=false]}
    \hline\hline
    {Fixed param.}                 &   {Values}        \\
    \hline
    $P$ [d]                        &   5.732436$^*$    \\
    $\dot{\omega } $ [$^\circ$/d]  &   0.004220$^*$    \\
    $q = M_2/M_1$                  &   0.41549$^{**}$  \\
    $e$                            &   0.07583$^{**}$  \\
    $T_{\mathrm{eff}_1}$ [K]       &   {31401$^{***}$} \\
    $T_{\mathrm{eff}_2}$ [K]       &   {25442$^{***}$} \\
    $L_{\mathrm{R}_3}$             &   0.273$^{***}$   \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^*$ \citet{Mayer2010}}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{**}$ from \texttt{KOREL}}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{***}$ from \texttt{Pyterpol}}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \caption{Solution to $\delta$ Orionis from \texttt{PHOEBE 1}.}
  \small
  \label{result}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format = 3.2(3)]}
      \toprule
      {Parameters}   &{Values}  \\
      \midrule
      $a$ [\Rnom]                   & 41.91(18)     \\
      $\omega$ [$^\circ$]           & 148.73(149)   \\
      $\gamma$ [ km/s)              & 21.96(33)     \\
      $i$ [$^\circ$]                & 78.1(3)       \\
      \midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \\
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = -2.3]}
      $M_1$ [\Mnom]                 &   21.1        \\
      $M_2$ [\Mnom]                 &   8.8         \\
      $R_1$ [\Rnom]                 &   13.6        \\
      $R_2$ [\Rnom]                 &   3.7         \\
      $M_{\mathrm{bol}_1}$ [mag]    &   -8.28       \\
      $M_{\mathrm{bol}_2}$ [mag]    &   -4.55       \\
      $L_{\mathrm{R}_1}$            &   0.690       \\
      $L_{\mathrm{R}_2}$            &   0.037       \\
      $\log g_1$  [cgs]             &   3.50        \\
      $\log g_2$ [cgs]              &   4.24        \\
      $ \chi^2_\mathrm{N}$          &  11.389       \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format=1.6, table-space-text-post={$^{***}$}, table-align-text-post=false]}
    \toprule
    {Fixed param.}                 &   {Values}        \\
    \midrule
    $P$ [d]                        &   5.732436$^*$    \\
    $\dot{\omega } $ [$^\circ$/d]  &   0.004220$^*$    \\
    $q = M_2/M_1$                  &   0.41549$^{**}$  \\
    $e$                            &   0.07583$^{**}$  \\
    $T_{\mathrm{eff}_1}$ [K]       &   {31401$^{***}$} \\
    $T_{\mathrm{eff}_2}$ [K]       &   {25442$^{***}$} \\
    $L_{\mathrm{R}_3}$             &   0.273$^{***}$   \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^*$ \citet{Mayer2010}}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{**}$ from \texttt{KOREL}}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{***}$ from \texttt{Pyterpol}}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, it is set by table-format?

Comment: I do not understand. Could I ask you for an adjustment to the new example code in my question, please?

Comment: Regarding "So, it is set by table-format": What does "it" refer to in this context?